# Uninitialized local variable c4700

Tags: c++

https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/structure-function

I'm learning how to pass structures to functions using the website above, I spent 2 hours of trying to figure out what was wrong with my program, I decided to copy and paste the code on the website to see if they did it correctly and the same error came up. If anyone could help it would be appreciated, there code below.

Warning C6001   Using uninitialized memory 'p'. Structure-Function  C:\DEV\C++\Structure-Function\Structure-Function\main.cpp   18

Error   C4700   uninitialized local variable 'p' used   Structure-Function  C:\DEV\C++\Structure-Function\Structure-Function\main.cpp   18

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Person {
    char name[50];
    int age;
    float salary;
};

Person getData(Person); 
void displayData(Person); 

int main()
{

    Person p;

    p = getData(p);   
    displayData(p);

    return 0;
}

Person getData(Person p) {

    cout << "Enter Full name: ";
    cin.get(p.name, 50);

    cout << "Enter age: ";
    cin >> p.age;

    cout << "Enter salary: ";
    cin >> p.salary;

    return p;
}

void displayData(Person p)
{
    cout << "\nDisplaying Information." << endl;
    cout << "Name: " << p.name << endl;
    cout <<"Age: " << p.age << endl;
    cout << "Salary: " << p.salary;
}
```

Comment: I'm not counting lines when they could have been numbered for us, but 
    p = getData(p); is passing p before you put anything in it.

Comment: The code exhibits undefined behavior, since you are passing `Person` by value to `getData`, and none of the members are initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to make the compiler happy and avoid the warning, initialize `p` before doing anything with it:

```
Person p = {};  // zero's out all the members (default initializes)
```

But the real issue is that you are passing an uninitialized instance of `Person` **by value** (a copy of p) into `getData`. The compiler wants to assume that objects passed by value are initialized - because most functions aren't written to expect uninitialized parameters.

And getData is returning another copy of Person back. While compilers have gotten efficient in recent years, it's still better to pass by reference.

```
void getData(Person& p) {

    cout << "Enter Full name: ";
    cin.get(p.name, 50);

    cout << "Enter age: ";
    cin >> p.age;

    cout << "Enter salary: ";
    cin >> p.salary;
}
```

Then simply invoke as:

```
getData(p);
```

The same instance of Person that's declared in `main` gets passed and returned from `getData`. As you have it now, multiple copies of `Person` are made along the way.